# Comparing the speed of startswith() .vs. in()

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, time

I was under the impression that `startswith` **has to be faster** than `in` for the simple reason that `in` has to do more checks *(allows for the word being looked for to be anywhere in the string)*. But I had my doubts so I decided to `timeit`. The code for the timings is given below and as you will probably notice I haven't done much timing; the code is rather simple.

```
import timeit

setup1='''
def in_test(sent, word):
    if word in sent:
        return True
    else:
        return False
'''

setup2='''
def startswith_test(sent, word):
    if sent.startswith(word):
        return True
    else:
        return False
'''

print(timeit.timeit('in_test("this is a standard sentence", "this")', setup=setup1))
print(timeit.timeit('startswith_test("this is a standard sentence", "this")', setup=setup2))
```

Results:

```
>> in:         0.11912814951705597
>> startswith: 0.22812353561129417
```

So `startswith` is twice as slow!.. I find this behavior very puzzling given what I said further above. Am I doing something wrong with timing the two or is `in` indeed faster? If so, why?

Note that the results are very similar even when they both return `False` (in this case, `in` would have to actually traverse the whole sentece in case it simply *short-circuited* before):

```
print(timeit.timeit('in_test("another standard sentence, would be that", "this")', setup=setup1))
print(timeit.timeit('startswith_test("another standard sentence, would be that", "this")', setup=setup2))

>> in:         0.12854891578786237
>> startswith: 0.2233201940338861
```

---

If **I** had to implement the two functions from scratch it would look something like this (pseudocode):

**`startswith`**: start comparing the letters of *word* to the letters of *sentence* one by one until a) word gets depleted (return True) or b) check returns False (return False)

**`in`**: call `startswith` for every position where the initial letter of *word* can be found in *sentence*.

I just don't get it..

---

Just to make it clear, `in` and `startswith` are **not equivallent**; I am just talking about the case where the word one is trying to find has to be the **first** in a string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you have to look-up and invoke a method. `in` is specialized and leads directly to `COMPARE_OP` (calling [`cmp_outcome`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L4933) which, in turn, calls `PySequence_Contains`) while `str.startswith` goes through slower byte-code:

```
2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (startswith)
4 LOAD_FAST                1 (word)
6 CALL_FUNCTION            1              # the slow part
```

Replacing `in` with `__contains__`, forcing a function call for that case too, pretty much negates the speed difference:

```
setup1='''
def in_test(sent, word):
    if sent.__contains__(word):
        return True
    else:
        return False
'''
```

And, the timings:

```
print(timeit.timeit('in_test("this is a standard sentence", "this")', setup=setup1))
print(timeit.timeit('startswith_test("this is a standard sentence", "this")', setup=setup2))
0.43849368393421173
0.4993997460696846
```

`in` is winning here because of the fact that it doesn't need to go through the whole function call setup and due to the favorable case it's presented with.

Comment: The favorable case does not seem to have such an influence; the pessimistic case yielded the same results. More like the length of the string and the overhead of `startswith`

Comment: I should be more verbose @Ev.Kounis :-) The length is what I meant as the favorable case. The fact that there's a match or not in a small string won't play much difference.

Comment: now we are back on the same page xD

Comment: cmp_outcome link https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4a8bcdf79cdb3684743fe1268de62ee88bada439/Python/ceval.c#L4933

Answer (score 6):

You're comparing an operator on strings -vs- an attribute lookup and a function call. The second one will have a higher overhead, even if the first one takes a long time on a lot of data.

Additionally you're looking for the first word, so if it does match, `in` will look at just as much data as `startswith()`. To see the difference you should look at a pessimistic case (no results found, or match at the end of the string):

```
setup1='''
data = "xxxx"*1000
def ....

print(timeit.timeit('in_test(data, "this")', setup=setup1))
0.932795189000899
print(timeit.timeit('startswith_test(data, "this")', setup=setup2))
0.22242475600069156
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The pessimistic case is already on the editted post.

Comment: Your pessimistic case is very short. Looking at 4 characters -vs- 40 is just a rounding error. Looking at 4 -vs- 4000 is where you start seeing the difference.

Comment: I understand but I would like to use either one of those to check small sentences like that and not entire texts. But it does make more sense now.

Comment: So we could argue that `in` is O(n) while `startswith` is O(c), but for small `n`s O(n) is better, right?

Comment: Exactly :) That's it

Answer (score 0):

If you look at bytecode produced by your functions:

```
>>> dis.dis(in_test)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (word)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (sent)
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               1 (True)
             15 RETURN_VALUE

  5     >>   16 LOAD_CONST               2 (False)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

you'll notice there is much overhead not directly related to string matching. Doing the test on a simpler function:

```
def in_test(sent, word):
    return word in sent
```

will be more reliable.